# Play Framework 2. Pass view into view

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I spent a few time learning Play 2 and now I want to generalize my project.
I have a view for rendering list of entities and now I want to pass another view as parameter which will render entity into this list. 
For example:

```
// showList.scala.html
@(entityList: List[Entity], /* Template for one Entity render. Named entityRenderer*/)
@for(entity <- entityList) 
 entityRenderer(entity)

// entityRenderer.scala.html
@(entity: Entity)
    @entity.getName()
```

which type entityRenderer should have?

I know each template is just a scala function but how to deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I would suggest the following:

```
// file main.scala.html
@(entityList: Page[models.Task]) // here we define a Page of entities
@for(entity <- entityList.getList) {
    <ul>
        @tags.entityRenderer(entity) // here we call another view passing the entity
    </ul>
}
```

And the other file:

```
// file entityRenderer.scala.html in package tags
@(entity: Task) // here we define the incoming arguments
     <li>entity.property</li>
```

Rember that the templates are basically compiled into functions. So you need to define the correct arguments and obviously pass the correct argument.

Comment: There is not what I mean. Now I have a situation exactly that you write. And this brings a bit code-repeating. In your example I want to pass tags.entityRenderer() as parameter to main.scala.html. Using this aproach I can render list of tasks, for example as list of small headers if I pass smallHeaderRenderer() or as a detailed list if I pass detailedRenderer(). By the way, maybe I misunderstood some base conception?